# Turn array into multidimensional assoc array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem with creating a dynamic assoc array based on a string.

**For example the following piece of code:**

```
Session::addSession('browser.history','stackoverflow');
```

This should return the following array: $_SESSION[TL_MODE]['browser']['history'] = 'stackoverflow';

**Current addSession function:**

```
public static function addSession($type, $value) {
            $_SESSION[TL_MODE][$type] = $value;
    }
```

I have been working on this for a couple of days and I still don't have a solution.

I hope someone could help me solve this problem, or if my approach is just wrong, I would like to know how I can achieve the same goal with a different approach.

**---UPDATE---**

Thanks to someone who saw this was a duplicated question. This is how I fixed it for my situation:

```
$temp = &$_SESSION[TL_MODE];
        $exploded = explode('.', $path);
        foreach($exploded as $key) {
            if(!is_array($temp[$key])) {
                $temp[$key] = array();
            }
            $temp = &$temp[$key];
        }
        $temp[] = $value;
        unset($temp);
```

Comment: add the complete code? what does addSession do?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta I will update my question.

Comment: exploding the first string on '.' and using each element as a key in the _SESSION array?

Comment: @sabas I tried that. When your array has more then 3 values, that doesnt work anymore

Comment: It's strange, there's no limit on dimensions

Comment: `Session::addSession('browser.history','stackoverflow');` vs `$_SESSION[TL_MODE]['browser']['history'] = 'stackoverflow';` i don't really see the point of the function